# New Relic Query Language for pod services in node

Tags: json, performance

What is the NRQL for viewing pod services in clusters.
Trying to view service pods to ensure they are evenly distributed across AZones.
Need the QL to trigger notification if the services within an AZ is < 15%
I had tried to write a QL but that was viewing the pods.

FROM K8sPodSample SELECT 100 * filter(uniqueCount(nodeName), WHERE ((isReady / (isScheduled + isReady)) > .50)) / uniqueCount(nodeName) AS '% Nodes with >50% Pod Usage' SINCE 5 minutes AGO FACET clusterName

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @mohammadmobasher.
I am trying to achieve the following:

Comment: Thanks @mohammadmobasher.
I am trying to achieve the following:

1. To show k8s pods and service are evenly distributed across cluster availability zones.
2. For service to trigger alert when distributions per availability zones is down by more than 15% of the desired distribution in the availability zone.

For pods, I can find "isScheduled" and "isReady" in the attributes. This is the QL I pasted above.
But for service, I am looking for the actual attributes that can return the distribution. If that makes sense.